# Map Object with Array as Values to Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have the following object with arrays as values:

```
{
  A: [{date: 21.01.2020, number: 4000}, {date: 22.01.2020, number: 3800}],

  B: [{date: 21.01.2020, number: 4000}, {date: 22.01.2020, number: 3800}],

  C: [{date: 21.01.2020, number: 4000}, {date: 22.01.2020, number: 3800}]
}
```

My goal is to translate this data into an array of objects:

```
[
 {
  "date": "21.01.2020",
  "A": 4000,
  "B": 4000,
  "C": 4000
 },
 {
  "date": "22.01.2020",
  "A": 3800,
  "B": 3800,
  "C": 3800
 }
]
```

I understand that I can get the individual keys (A,B,C) from the current object by using:

```
Object.keys(...)
```

My problem is that I don't want to map through the current object itself, but I need to map through the values of the current object, the array containing the data that I need (the initial object contains 3 key value pairs, the goal is to transform this into 2 objects).

What would be the best way to map through the values of the object and to create the array?

Comment: You can also do [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) which will get you the keys and the values. I’d recommend that plus a [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). I’ll post some example code when I get to a keyboard if you don’t have an answer by then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this approach by using only `forEach`. On this method, I first group the data by date and then return the values of the object into an array.

```js
const data = {
 A: [{date: '21.01.2020', number: 4000}, {date: '22.01.2020', number: 3800}],
 B: [{date: '21.01.2020', number: 4000}, {date: '22.01.2020', number: 3800}],
 C: [{date: '21.01.2020', number: 4000}, {date: '22.01.2020', number: 3800}]
};

const res = {};

// Group the data object by the date and make another object
Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
    data[key].forEach(value => {
 if (typeof res[value.date] == 'undefined') {
     res[value.date] = {};
 }
 res[value.date].date = value.date;
 res[value.date][key] = value.number;
    });
});

// Finally make the object as array of object
const output = Object.values(res);
console.log(output);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get the entries and then iterate the array.

This approach uses an object as hash table and returns only the values of the hash table.

```js
var data = { A: [{ date: '21.01.2020', number: 4000 }, { date: '22.01.2020', number: 3800 }], B: [{ date: '21.01.2020', number: 4000 }, { date: '22.01.2020', number: 3800 }], C: [{ date: '21.01.2020', number: 4000 }, { date: '22.01.2020', number: 3800 }] },
    result = Object.values(Object.entries(data).reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
        v.forEach(({ date, number }) => (r[date] = r[date] || { date })[k] = number);
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```